# Getting error on windows 7, while executing "npm run deploy". I am trying to deploy my code to pages.github.com

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, github-pages

bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/8984

> Same problem but I worked around it by changing the git remote url to
>   include my git username and password.
>
> List your remote URL using:
>
> git remote -v Update the remote URL to include username and password
>   just before github.com:
>
> git remote set-url
>   https://:@github.com//.git
>   Not sure why this was necessary, I thought I'd be prompted for my
>   credentials if git didn't know them.
>
> More details, hopefully relevant:
>
> OS Windows 10 Git version is 2.6.0 from http://git-scm.com/ Recently
>   done a Windows re-install

good video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKXkC4SqtRk